# Escape a double backslash in java/sql

Tags: java, mysql, backslash

I need to prepare a query for my `preparedStatement` to find some specific data but I'm having issue with `the double backslash (\\)`, as I could escape all the rest but not this one, `SQL` needs four backslashes to work poperly and `Java` as we know changes every two backslashes to one so I couldn't get four in the row.

Any ideas would be very helpful.

Here is my method :

```
public static String escapeMetaCharacters(String inputString){
    final String[] metaCharacters = {"\\","^","$","{","}","[","]","(",")",".","*","+","?","|","<",">","-","&"};
    String outputString="";
    for (int i = 0 ; i < metaCharacters.length ; i++){
        if(inputString.contains(metaCharacters[i])){
            outputString = inputString.replace(metaCharacters[i],"\\"+metaCharacters[i]);
            inputString = outputString;
        }
    }
    return outputString;
}
```

Comment: You say you need four backslashes; Java changes two backslashes in a string literal to one; does `"\\\\\\\\"` not work? What happened when you tried it?

Comment: It might be easier to state the actual problem you are trying to solve, then the workaround you are attempting to create.

Comment: Somehow, if you are doing this, the eerie feeling pops up that this is not the right way to solve your problem. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: I'm just trying to escape double backslashes guys, and backslashes in sql doesn't work with REGEXP for exp. That's the actual problem. I don't need to give you the actual sql.

Comment: But the thing is, *why* are you trying to escape double backslashes (I cannot think of an example where that is needed)? If we understand the root problem, we can better help you.

Comment: @BartFriederichs The only thing I can think of is to have a literal in a SQL regular expression; however then I would expect 4 backslashes to be sufficient.

Comment: select ... REGEXP 'blablabla\\blabla\\blabla', this query doesn't show anything unless I add two backslahes in front of each two backslashes so it could be understood by  mysql